# Como abrir conexão com 2 tabelas no php

Tags: php, html, sql, banco-de-dados

Estou com dificuldade de conseguir conectar duas vezes no meu banco de dados, cada vez irá conectar a uma tabela
o código e o seguinte:

**Categorias**

```
<!-- Portfolio Grid -->
    <section class="bg-light" id="portfolio">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Categorias</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
    <?php
      require_once "conecta_db.php"; //CHAMA O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM BD

      $tb = "categorias";
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$tb;
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

      while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
      {     
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
            <a class="portfolio-link"  href="<?php echo "categorias.php?idcat=".$linha["idcat"];?>">
                  <div class="portfolio-hover">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">

                 <h4><?php echo utf8_encode ($linha["nome"]); ?></h4>
                            <?php echo "<img class=\"img-fluid\"  src=\"img/servicos/".$linha["idcat"].".png\">"; ?>                    
                    <p class="text-muted"><?php echo utf8_encode ($linha["descricao"]);?></p>
                </div>
            </a>
          </div>
   <?php } // fecha while
     // Free result set
     mysqli_free_result($result);
     mysqli_close($con);
   ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="bg-light" id="servicos">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
            <h2 class="section-heading text-uppercase">Serviços</h2>
            <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted"></h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
     <?php
        require_once "conecta_db.php"; //CHAMA O ARQUIVO DE CONEXÃO COM BD

       $tbb = "servicos";
       $sqll = "SELECT * FROM ".$tb;
       $resultt=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

       while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt))
       {    
     ?>       
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
            <a class="portfolio-link"  href="<?php echo "categorias.php?idcat=".$linha["idsv"];?>">
                  <div class="portfolio-hover">
                    <div class="portfolio-hover-content">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus fa-3x"></i>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="portfolio-caption">

                 <h4><?php echo utf8_encode ($linha["nome"]); ?></h4>
                            <?php echo "<img class=\"img-fluid\"  src=\"img/sv/".$linha["idsv"].".png\">"; ?>                   
                    <p class="text-muted"><?php echo utf8_encode ($linha["descricao"]);?></p> 

                </div>
            </a>
          </div>
      <?php } // fecha while
       // Free result set
       mysqli_free_result($result);
       mysqli_close($con);
      ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Qual o erro está sendo mostrado?

Comment: Warning
: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
167


Warning
: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
169


Warning
: mysqli_free_result(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
193


Warning
: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
194

Answer (score 0):

neste excerto

```html
$tbb = "servicos";
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM ".$tb;
$resultt=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt))
{
```

voce declarou as variaveis como $tbb e $sqll, mas utilizou-as de outra forma.

tente assim:

```html
$tbb = "servicos";
$sqll = "SELECT * FROM ".$tbb;
$resultt=mysqli_query($con,$sqll);

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultt))
{
```

Comment: esta dando o seguinte erro: Warning
: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
167


Warning
: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
169
Warning
: mysqli_free_result(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_result in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
193


Warning
: mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tcc\startbootstrap-agency-gh-pages\index.php
on line
194